# Techniques implement polymorphism but save on the 4 bytes

Tags: c#, c++, optimization

I came across a technique in template metadata programming which allows to implement polymorphism without the virtual function mechanism.

Hence I am wondering if there are some other tricks one can use to do polymorphic behavior in c++ or C#?

EDIT : also sometime ago i read that visitor design pattern is an alternative to virtual mechanism, but cannot recall the article. can someone confirm it it can be used too?

EDIT2 : I understand it is not an ideal programming practice, but hack is what I am looking for since optimization is of primary concern. The classes hierarchy is assigned during compile time (the pointers are not assigned to the classes during run time by if-else logic, etc.)

Comment: Why do you need to save on 4 bytes?  Unless you're running this on a watch or something, it really doesn't matter...

Comment: i want to put the objects in a large array..

Comment: @tjameson, and even [watches](http://www.i4u.com/5802/new-java-wrist-watch-jblend) run Java nowadays :)

Comment: How large? 4 bytes is nothing. For example, if you have 1,000,000 entries, that's less than 4 megabytes.  You're going to have larger problems than saving a couple megabytes...

Comment: How big are the objects? Do they really only contain a 4 byte vtable?

Answer (score 3):

Do you ever wonder *why* polymorphism tends to add around 4 bytes of overhead per use? It's because *that's the simplest, most practical way to implement polymorphism*. There are grotesque hacks possible that can simulate C++/C#/Objective-C polymorphism with less overhead, but they come with great tradeoffs--several times the CPU usage per call, for instance, or statically-stored class hierarchies with limited extensibility.

Polymorphism is implemented the way it is implemented because the way it is implemented is already optimal.

Comment: He could always use a struct for his data and implement polymorphism apart from it with pointers to the actual data...

Comment: Well, he said he wants to optimize away the 4 bytes of the polymorphism, not the pointer. Haha. Anyway, this would take the memory away from the array and put it elsewhere (he'd have to create a new object everytime he wanted to access his data though, but no more 4 bytes =D).

Answer (score 3):

(EDIT: This is answer is in the context of C#.)

You're not going to save 4 bytes *per object* anyway. The type will still have a single vtable to lookup function member implementations. You might save one entry in that table by avoiding a virtual method, but that's a single entry in a single object - it's not going to affect you on a per-instance basis.

Either you're missing something, or I am. It would help if you could edit the question to show what you're trying to do in the most *natural* implementation - then explain where you're trying to save space.

Comment: @Jerry: Whereas in C#, *every* reference type object has a single reference to its actual type, regardless of how many virtual methods there are...

Answer (score 2):

Templates can only be used to implement compile-time polymorphism. I'm not aware of any mechanism to implement runtime polymorphism without a space overhead, but why does it matter? If you need runtime polymorphism to solve your problem, you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to save memory, you could implement your own memory handling. Block headers and footers are larger than 4 bytes each (I think they're 8 bytes each), so putting everything in a huge memory block and doing your own indexing would be the way to go.  Don't even use objects, just binary indices.

My point is, unless you're designing low-level databases, OS kernels, or a [SOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System-on-a-chip), you really shouldn't be worrying about this.  Especially with C#. Do you know how much overhead garbage collection has??

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of tricks varying from well known techniques (e.g., the CRTP in C++) to rather ugly hacks (I once roughly quintupled the capacity of a particular program by eliminating vtable pointers; instead, I implemented a separate allocator for each of the classes, and found the correct vtable based on the object's address).

The visitor pattern really just *displaces* polymorphism rather than *replacing* it. In other words, what could/would have been polymorphic behavior in the class being visited is moved into the visitor class. To get dynamic binding, however, you still have a hierarchy of visitor classes, typically using the usual vtable mechanism to implement polymorphism. Under the right circumstances, this can still save a fair amount of memory though, as the number of visitor objects is often much smaller than the number of objects they visit.

Comment: Found good use cases for C++/CRTP (as described by Alexandrescu) in embedded programming projects with limited RAM.  I have to agree that polymorphism via OO is more natural -- leading to cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/variant/index.html) is a C++ library implementation of the visitor design pattern that avoids dynamic polymorphism.

And for your edification, the C++ static polymorphism approach you mentioned has a name: [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).